# Checking licence and yes/no load of dll/dependencies techniques

Tags: c#, dynamic, dll, licensing

What are the different ways to load a assembly/dll from a executing caller. I'm thinking in the context of licensing, if the dll is licensed, then load it. I've looked at MEF, seems a bit granular, heavy. Is the only other dynamic loading.

Comment: Not really clear what do you mean, sorry. Can you give an example of a scenario?

Comment: I have a assembly which is licensed. Normally for a assembly, I would reference it in vs2k10 and use it. If I reference in the vs project, and it's not licensed by me, then it will still ship as a dll. Scenario is I check the license server, yip dll is licensed, load the dll, other no. How to load it. I've had a look at MEF/MAF and i'm not really looking for that. Is the only other way to load a dll by a caller, dynamic loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx) method.  You load the assembly from a file (or URI, etc), and then access it via reflection.  Sound right?

Comment: yea sounds right, sounds ancient as well. Is that the standard way of doing it?

Comment: Well there are plenty of wrappers and DI tools built around it, but this is the basis for all of them as far as I am aware.

Comment: How would it work if the assembly is a windows service? One windows service calling another, or not?

Comment: Assemblies are assemblies.  Loading one assembly within another does not execute it or start another process, it just loads the code (as if it were a DLL).  Nothing special about windows services in that regard.

Comment: I knew that, in 2002-03, I forgot about it. In 4 months time, i'll have forgotten about it, and have the delight of discovering it again, like a lost gem.